# NoClassDefFoundError found for Vuforia upgrade

Tags: eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror, vuforia

Vuforia have upgraded their library to patch a bug and I have to update it in a hurry.

I went from 2.5.7 to 2.8.8 and I've taken the following steps:

- adjust the eclipse global `QCAR_SDK_ROOT` variable to point to the new directory;
- append "-o" to the name of the old directory to ensure I'm not accidentally referencing obsolete libraries;
- change the **external jar reference** in my project to point to the new jar, and added that jar to the **order and export** tab (yes, I checked it!);
- changed the makefile to point to the new location;
- changed references to `QCAR::Tracker::IMAGE_TARGET` to `QCAR::ImageTracker::getClassType()` (a header has changed);
- removed the armeabi build from the makefile so only the armeabi-v7a is operational;
- completely cleaned and rebuilt everything;
- restarted eclipse.

When I try and run the app, `QCAR::onResume()` causes a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I really can't think of a step I've missed and /bin/dexedLibs/ contains a Vuforia-4e3d2406...etc.jar.  The application does reference an external jar, **but** it did before and worked.  It also references a separate external jar, but one built from a secondary project (which is also referenced in the Android properties and java build path).  What could I have done wrong?

Vuforia developer forum post:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/noclassdeffounderror-upgraded-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native library in 2.5.7 was called libQCAR.so.  The native library in 2.8.8 is called libVuforia.so.  I needed to change

```
System.loadLibrary("QCAR");
```

to

```
System.loadLibrary("Vuforia");
```